# Error adding adblock to Chrome python selenium webdrive

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, adblock

I tried to add adblock to the selenium using this code:

```
chop =webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chop.add_extension('Adblock-Plus_v1.4.1.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chop)
```

I got this error:

```
'OSError: Path to the extension doesn't exist'
```

what should I do?

Comment: where you've kept the 'Adblock-Plus_v1.4.1.crx' file!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the full path:

```
from os import path

chop =webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chop.add_extension(path.abspath('Adblock-Plus_v1.4.1.crx'))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chop)
```